# Complex count row etl requirement

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement related as below

1-If there is employee record then count the number of rows

```
  a-if there are four rows then follow the layout 1,

         and populate the column1 and column 2 with values in report and ltrimrtrim

  b- if there are three rows, then follow the layout 2,

         and hardcode the column 1 and column 2 with NULL
```

Otherwise, look for the employee record.

Couldn't get the logic, I used the router with as if column 1 and two null the send to layout two else 1. But the requirement is different.

router transformation, if null, layout one else 2

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please try to rephrase and possibly illustrate the problem? I'd be glad to help, but I honestly can't get the root of the problem. Some example input and desired output would help me a lot.

Comment: can you try to give us what is your input and how the output should look. this will help us to help you. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Use SRT>AGG>JNR to calculate count. create new column as count_all and set to COUNT(*). Please group by proper key columns.
Step 2 - Use RTR next to split data based on your condition.

1. group 1- count_all =4 then follow the layout 1 and...
2. group 2- count_all =3 then follow the layout 2 and...
3. group 3 - if count <3 then do  employee record.